# why is safari the only browser flagging my https website as not secure

Tags: html, https, safari, ssl-certificate, web-deployment

I recently created a website for my client's business. We bought and setup an OV SSL certificate from GoDaddy, the same platform we're hosting on. But for some reason, Safari is flagging the whole site as not secure, whilst Chrome and Edge are saying its secure. All the links on the website have an HTTPS prefix and all the images are hosted on the server. Its only a small website advertising his business, its got about 5 pages. Why is Safari flagging the site as  not secure? Please help.

Comment: How are you opening the site? are you typing in the hostname without `https`? If so, it might be related to the some browser vendors pushing for https by default, meaning the browser would try https first, and fall back to http if not possible. Without that, the website needs to enforce https connections by a 301 HTTP Redirect, and optionally also by means of HSTS. If not, the browser will simply stay on http, which is unsecure.

Comment: So turns out that was actually the case. I had not configured for http clients to be redirected because i thought it had automatically been done when i saw that chrome and edge were connecting with https, albeit that was only because they force an https connection unlike Safari i suppose. Creds to you Andy, much appreciated.

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Would you mind accepting my answer if this helped you and you don’t have further questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers auto-complete the URL schema when an address or hostname is typed in. Currently, there are some browsers auto-completing to `https://`, while some still autocomplete to `http://`. The latter seems to be the case with Safari.

So actually, Safari is marking your *http* website as unsecure, which is as expected.

For several years now browser vendors have been transitioning to encryption by default, taking increasingly strict measures to do so, like connecting on https by default.

The [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/) also specifies which hosts should be connected to on secure connections only. Safari will probably autocomplete the URL with `https://` if the typed in hostname can be found in that list.

---

A website usually can be reached on both schemes when a certificate is installed. So one would add a 301 redirect from `http` to `https` to force every one to use the encrypted connection. This redirect is missing in your configuration. Often, it can be activated with a simple checkbox in the web hoster’s configuration pages.

It is best practice to preserve all other parts of the request during the redirect, except the schema, so that existing links still work. e.g. `http://example.com/test.html`  would redirect to `https://example.com/test.html`

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling IPv6 on your current network, just to check if this is related to IPv6.

On Mac you can disable IPv6 by going ***System Preferences->Network->{YourConnection}->Advaned->TCP/IP***, and change **IPv6** to **Manually**